# Wobbly sound FL Studio

Tags: design, sound, studio, fl-studio, loop

I am writing a song on FL Studio, but when I have another instrument along with my main melody, the main melody sort of quietens every beat of the secondary instrument. It's very strange.
I have experimented with different levels, and pans, but nothing works.

Thanks in advance, I am grateful for any answers :)

Ok, my main instrument is a guitar with a compressor.
My secondary instruments are lots of quiet instruments, with no effects on them.
They are instruments such as Wasp XT, Poizone and Greasy Wobble.

youtu.be/0TJjUl9ZnHU

Answer (score 2):

Is the compression applied correctly?  It sounds like you are applying compression to the overall signal rather than just the guitar.  In that case, if the secondary instrument gets louder, it could trigger the compression of the entire signal resulting in a reduction in the signal level of everything else going in to the compressor that was at static level.

Update: after listening to your sample, it sounds a bit like some form of destructive bump interference, but I'm not sure from what.  Do you have anything doing any phasing on it?

Comment: I definitely only applied the compressor to guitar

Comment: No idea then, can you post a clip of what it sounds like?  SoundCloud works very well as they embed and have a cross linking agreement with SE as I recall.

Comment: http://youtu.be/0TJjUl9ZnHU is the link. Thank you very much :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I added reverb to some instruments but that's all

Comment: @olly was it a delay reverb? Basically you have some constant frequency tones and if you offset then just right you get phase interference like that. A delay reverb could cause that.

Comment: It was frooty reverb 2

Comment: Yeah, there is a delay there.  Try tweaking the delay a bit and see if it impacts the worble.

Comment: Can i email you the full mp3 track? Im a bit unsure about putting it on youtube. Please, is there a way you can safely tell me your email? or remove the comment when I see it? I think what happens is that there is too much on one side of the speaker.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used FL Studio before but could you provide more information? I am thinking if it's a sub bass and/or bass or kick drum it could be if you are using side chain plugin that alot of the lows are fading out creating a wobble effect. Please provide more info.

Comment: Ok, my main instrument is a guitar with a compressor. My secondary instruments are lots of quiet instruments, with no effects on them. They are instruments such as Wasp XT, Poizone and Greasy Wobble

Comment: Is it an audible wobble or is more like a flanger sound or something like that?

Comment: Not like a wobble, it is hard to explain.

Comment: It just makes the track sound awful, and it didn't happen in Logic. The track that is effected is the only one that has the compressor on. The track even 'wobbles' when all instruments are realllyyy quiet!

Comment: Can you post the example on youtube and share the link?

Comment: http://youtu.be/0TJjUl9ZnHU

Comment: What do you think it could be?

Comment: It almost sounds like you changed the tempo. Check that to make sure it's still the same bpm

Comment: Yeh it is all the same

Comment: To be honest, I don't know how to

Comment: If you don't know how, then it's on 140 bpm. That's the default setting.

Comment: So do you have any idea what the problem could be? Can you hear it?

Comment: Try changing the bpm to your apporiate setting of the song

Comment: I don't think that will work. It's something to do with the second instruments

Comment: I would try it, rule some possibilities out atleast. It's sounds like the same thing that happens in logic and Reason.

Comment: Didn't work- plus I never changed it. Thanks for all your help. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Is it from midi or did you record it?

Comment: I just put it into the piano roll

Comment: I would try to a new project and start over. Sorry, I am not sure what would be wrong with it.